# Defining a custom environment with per-section numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, environments

I have an `enumerate` environment that I want to refer to later in my document using `\ref` and `\label`, but `enumerate` doesn't get numbered by section (the way, say, `figure` would). How can I add section numbers to `enumerate`?

I do not want individual, enumerated items to be numbered. Rather, I want the enumeration as a whole to be numbered.

What I am really looking for is something like this:

---

Algorithm 1.2

1. Walk to store.
    2. Buy Milk 
    3. Walk Home

... /*snip*/ ...

As described in Algorithm 1.2, it's easy to buy milk.

---

I don't want to use a figure because I can't have it moving around the document. I don't want to use the theorem/definition/proof environments because of all the styling. The algorithm environments use a lot of styling too. I'm basically looking for a way to slap a title on my enumerate environment and give it a number that I can refer to.

**Edit:**

This is what I finally ended up with, based on Mico's post:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{algcounter}
\newenvironment{alg}{
\bigskip\noindent
\refstepcounter{algcounter}
\textbf{Algorithm \thealgcounter}
\newline
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{\end{enumerate}}
\numberwithin{algcounter}{section}
```

Comment: Next time, please state your full requirements at the start. That'll save potential helpers some work.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you don't want to use a theorem environment. I think what you are asking is a specific type of a theorem. It is relatively easy to change the style of theorem, for example, by using the `ntheorem` package.

Comment: @Jake: Do you want to use the algorightm-environment. Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: @Macro-Daniel algorithmic might work, but again, it's not numbered. I really need the numbering at the top. I need a big fat number sitting in front of my algorithm so that I can refer to it later.

Comment: @Aditya If there is a way to make the theorem environment look like the enumerate environment but have proper numbering then I'd be fine with that. I don't care how it's done. I just want normal styling with a number at the top that I can refer to.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I see your first name is being (mis)spelled as "Macro". Welcome to the club -- my first name frequently gets misspelled "Micro".

Comment: @Jake: I edit my answer.

Comment: @Mico: We have difficult names ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Sorry! Just realized I misspelled that, too late to edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're willing to load the `amsmath` package (you may be doing so already anyway...), you can just issue the command

```
\numberwithin{enumi}{section}
```

to have level-1 enumerations be subordinated to the section.

**Addendum.** From your follow-up remarks, it would appear that you're not trying to change the appearance of LaTeX's own `enumerate` environment but, instead, want to create a custom environment that will be numbered within sections. (I.e., each time a `\section` command is encountered, numbering should start over at "1"; however, the section number needs to be prefixed to the environment number.) The following MWE illustrates how this may be achieved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % needed for its \numberwithin command
\newcounter{myalgctr}

\newenvironment{myalg}{%      define a custom environment
   \bigskip\noindent%         create a vertical offset to previous material
   \refstepcounter{myalgctr}% increment the environment's counter
   \textsc{Algorithm \themyalgctr}% or \textbf, \textit, ...
   \newline%
   }{\par\bigskip}  %          create a vertical offset to following material
\numberwithin{myalgctr}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

Some text before the first algorithm environment \ldots

\begin{myalg}
Some thoughts\ldots \label{alg:first}
\end{myalg}

\begin{myalg}
More thoughts\ldots \label{alg:second}
\end{myalg}

Some text after the second algorithm environment \ldots

\section{Second section}

\begin{myalg}
Further thoughts\ldots \label{alg:third}
\end{myalg}

\section{Third section}

As we showed in algorithms \ref{alg:first}, \ref{alg:second}, 
and \ref{alg:third}, \ldots 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Similarly to @Macro-Daniel's answer, I need numbering for the environment as a whole, not the individual items.

Comment: @Jake: I've provided an addendum to my answer. I now interpret your question as pertaining to a custom environment that is to be numbered within sections.

Comment: How does one make `\newenvironment` play well with `fancyhdr`? Right now it doesn't pick up the section mark at all from environments defined this way.

Comment: @level1807 - I'm very sorry, but my mind-reading skills are absolutely worthless. I also have no idea how your query relates to anything in the answer above, which I wrote more than 8 years ago. May I suggest that you post a *new query*, in which you would lay out which issues you're encountering and what you've tried so far? Ideally, your query would be accompanied by a [Minimum (Non-)Working Example]((http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001)). A new query has the very important benefit of being seen by far more people than a comment below an 8-year-old posting.

Answer (score 9):

EDIT:

Based on the new informations of the comments I provide a new answer.

To type an algorithm you can work the the package `algorihtm`. By using the command `numberwithin` (provided by `amsmath`) you can set the counter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{algorithm}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm}\label{algo}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require $x\ge5$
\Ensure $x\le-5$
\Statex
\While{$x>-5$}
\State $x\gets x-1$
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\ref{algo}
\end{document}
```

### [image]

To manipulate list environments like `enumerate` I really recommend the package `enumitem`. The package provides the key `ref` to manipulate the format of references.

Here an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{ref=\thesection.\theenumi}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
Text
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{enum1} foo
\item \label{enum2} bar
\end{enumerate}

\ref{enum1} and \ref{enum2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please consider to add a variant using `label` and `resume`, so I can delete my answer.

Comment: This is close but not what I need...I edited my question to be a bit clearer