# Custom command which increments alphabetically

Tags: numbering, environments

I want to create a custom command, e.g. `\foo`, which contains a counter which increments alphabetically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    
\foo % foo A
Some random text

\foo % foo B
Some more random text

\foo % foo C
Even more random text

\end{document}
```

Doing it manually might look something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\bigskip\noindent
foo A
\par\bigskip
Some random text

\bigskip\noindent
foo B
\par\bigskip
Some more random text

\bigskip\noindent
foo C
\par\bigskip
Even more random text

\end{document}
```

I got the `\bigskip` idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43499/266984

I just don't know a way to get the A, B, C increments.

I don't think I'll ever get beyond the letter Z - so it's not required to factor this in. Also this `\foo` doesn't have to appear in a table of contents or anything.

Comment: why not a standard list or heading, both of which do this? but `\newcounter{foo}\newcommand\foo{\refstepcounter{foo}Foo \thefoo\par}`  would do what you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably better to use an `itemize` environment personalized (see package `enumitem` or similar), but --- quick and dirty solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{foocnt}
\newcommand{\foo}{\refstepcounter{foocnt}foo \Alph{foocnt}\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}

\foo % foo A
Some random text

\foo % foo B
Some more random text

\foo % foo C
Even more random text

\end{document}
```

[image: output from the snippet above]

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into itemize. But your solution works really well